# VUEJS components adding my show route to their get call, how can I get my journals/:id pages to work. Mime Error

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm getting a Mime type error: Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/journals/assets/css/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I have narrowed the error down to this section here: "localhost:8080/journals" as the /journals is causing my app to receive a 404 error on any of my journal show pages. I load all my components in my App.vue file.

```
<component is="script" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></component>
<component is="script" src="assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js">
</component>
<component is="script" src="assets/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js">
</component>
<component is="script" src="assets/js/jquery.scrollex.min.js">
</component>
<component is="script" src="assets/js/browser.min.js">
</component>
<component is="script" src="assets/js/breakpoints.min.js">
</component>
<component is="script" src="assets/js/util.js">
</component>
<component is="script" src="assets/js/main.js">
</component>
```

Any clues on why my app is forcing the '/journals' into my get requests?

Trying to load HTML5UP css/etc to a show route.

Picture of my [VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs7yJ.jpg) for reference.

Comment: Probably best to put that sort of thing in the `public` folder. See https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html

Comment: Hi, it was included in the public folder from html5up, so it already as and has been accessed by all my other routes. The problem is when I try to add another '/:id' onto my url using a route, AKA looking deeper at a journal post, those public access folders are trying to be called upon with a get request that adds "/journals" before the src routes.

Answer (score -1):

So, after testing all last night and this morning, I came across my real problem. My scripts being loaded in App.vue were not the problem. In my index.html file I did not have a "/" before "assets/" in "" which caused it to try and load those scripts incorrectly.